# Class Transition Predict Outcome Variable

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I have some longitudinal data that is was collected in waves. At each wave, participants either do or do not have variable of interest (yes/no). I want to look at different classes of variable (i.e., transition from no to yes; yes to no; or continuing yes/no). I want this transition class to predict various outcome variables.
Should I just use a regression for this after coding for transition class? Or am I thinking about this all wrong?
I looked at a latent class analysis, latent transition analysis and multistate markov models but it looks like all of these predict the odds of transitioning between the classes. I am not interested in odds of transitioning but how the different transitions predict the outcome variable.
Thank you for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try a mover-stayer model. The mover-stayer latent classes can be related to outcome variables. For example, it can be looked at whether the means (or proportions for categorical variables) of outcome variables differ across movers versus stayers. For relevant references, see

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C49&q=mover+stayer+model&btnG=